# Is Electromagnetic radiation off power lines charged particles or ionized electrons?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Electromagnetic radiation: (image from OP)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is Electromagnetic radiation off power lines charged particles or ionized electrons?

[image]

Image Source [Sources of Ionisation](http://www.mcw.edu/Radiation-Oncology/Radiation-Biology/Power-Lines-Cancer-FAQs.htm#2)

Neither, is the short answer. Although the voltage is high, you can see from the diagram above that the power lines used to carry electrical power from electricity generators to your local substation have far too low a frequency to produce ionisation.

Radiation from power lines is carried by low energy photons, which are non ionising.